# Flutter Custom Widget Property Transfer

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to create a custom widget for TextField widget and I want to transfer all properties to my custom widget. I have used in React Native ...props syntax.

My custom Widget:

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      border: Border.all(
        color: Colors.grey,
        width: 1,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
  margin: margin,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        labelText: label,
        border: InputBorder.none,
        counterText: ""),
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    //I want to put here custom widget properties
  ),
);
```

I want to use custom widget like:

```
Input(
    label: "Şifre",
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: marginBottom),
    obscureText: true, //**
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.send, //**
    controller: passwordController, //**
)
```

I want to transfer commented ** properties to custom widget commented line

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [TextField](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) but look for a [TextFormField](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) instead. It gathers all the properties you are asking for.

```
  TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        labelText: label,
        border: InputBorder.none,
        counterText: ""),
        obscureText: true,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
        controller: passwordController,
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But this is a sample using. I want to use this for another widgets. Is there a any way to make this? I researched but I don't have a result.

Comment: What do you mean? You can use a `TextFormField` whenever you want. It's a widget after all.

Comment: I want to create a Global widget but I don't want to create all properties manually. In react native {...props} syntax make this. Is a a same using in flutter?

Comment: But you’ve all of these properties in a `TextFormField` widget already. I don’t get what you really want.

Comment: TextField was an example. I just want to give other widget's features to another widget. For example, I want to create a custom camera widget that have all properties a button widget. I hope I could tell you what I wanted.